# Upload button on Instagram won't accept Selenium send_keys

Tags: python, selenium, file-upload, instagram, sendkeys

I am coding a Selenium bot (with Python) that uploads a picture to instagram from a queue in a directory. For now, I have successfully logged in on Instagram and I am now trying to interact somehow with the upload button.

I have tried to click() on it, but then a window pops up where I would normally browse my computer to find the image I want to upload. I've found that I need `import autoit`, but I can't understand how it works and the documentation doesn't help either, so I'd rather avoid using this.

This is what I have for now:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


class InstaBot():

# A COOKIES POP UP ALWAYS APPEARS UPON OPENING INSTAGRAM, SO INIT ALSO CLOSES IT
# TO UPLOAD ON INSTAGRAM, THE MOBILE VERSION IS NEEDED, WE TRY TO EMULATE A GALAXY S5
    def __init__(self):
        mobile_emulation = {"deviceName": "Galaxy S5"}
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
            #   experimental options for mobile emulation added
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options = chrome_options)
        self.driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
        
            #   note that this accepts all cookies
        cooki = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/button[1]')
        cooki.click()

# FINDS THE USERNAME AND PASSWORD AND TYPES 2 INPUTS ACCORDINGLY
    def loginfun(self):   
        entrar = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div/div/div/div[2]/button')))
        entrar.click()
        
        usbar = pasbar = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div[1]/div[3]/div/label/input')
        usbar.send_keys(input('Username: '))
        # once usbar is found, the rest will be as well
        pasbar = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div[1]/div[4]/div/label/input')
        pasbar.send_keys(input('Password: '))
        
        logbtn = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div[1]/div[6]/button')
        logbtn.click()


# CLOSES PASSWORD SAVING AND NOTIFICATION MESSAGES IN CASE THEY APPEAR
    def tryclose(self):
        try:
            nopass = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/div/div/button')))
            nopass.click()
        except Exception:
            pass
        
        try:
            nonot = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div/div[3]/button[2]')))
            nonot.click()
        except Exception:
            pass


# bla bla bla
# Basically I emulate a mobile device and log into my account,
# then I have at the bottom center of the page the upload button that
# looks like this [+]. Here is what I try:


#   SELECTS THE FIRST IMAGE FROM THE PENDING DIR. USES THE UPLOAD BUTTON VIA SEND_KEYS.
#   AFTER THAT, IT MOVES SAID IMAGE TO THE 'DONE' DIR.
    def upload(self):
            # first pending image
        pend_img = (os.listdir('C:/path to my queue dir')[0])

            # finds the upload button and send_keys the image to it
        upbtn = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/nav[2]/div/div/form/input')
        upbtn.send_keys('C:/path to image in queue'+pend_img)

            # moves the image to the 'done' directory
        os.rename('C:/path to image in queue dir'+pend_img , \
                  'C:/path to image in done dir'+pend_img)
```

After this process, this code is able to find the image in the 'pending' (queue) directory and move it to the 'done' directory,  **BUT** it does not interact with instagram whatsoever. So `send_keys()` is not working. I am a newbie in this, but I recon that the HTML path to the button `upbtn` may be wrong, although I cannot find any other input path or anything.

NOTE: to clarify, no errors are shown, the problem is just that send_keys does not interact with the upload button with this code.

Anyone has a fool-proof solution or an intuitive way to upload to Instagram?

Following advice from the comments, I looked for all the input tags in the HTML of the page:

[image]

After my search, these are all the XPaths to the input tags I could find, all of them have `type="file"`:

```
//*[@id="react-root"]/form/input
//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div[1]/form/input       
//*[@id="react-root"]/section/nav[1]/div/div/form/input  # this one is for stories i think
//*[@id="react-root"]/section/nav[2]/div/div/form/input  # it should be this one
```

I have tried `send_keys()` to all of them, yet none seems to work.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Basically the "bla bla bla" part :)

Comment: you can probably use Selenium here.  What you do is use send_keys targeting the <input> tag of type="file"... it'll set the 'value' of that input tag, then you can click to upload.  Include the markup of the page in question so we can take a look.

Comment: @Yatin Sorry I didn't think it was necessary. I uploaded the full code in case you want to take a look at it.

Comment: @pcalkins In my first post Stackoverflow wouldn't let me upload a pic, sorry about that. You can see now the whole markup of the page.

Comment: somewhere in that form there is probably an <input> tag of type=file.  That's what you want to target.  You send it the path to your file.  You can right-click to "inspect" in your browser.  Then copy relevant bits to your clipboard so you can paste into your post.  It helps a lot if the code and markup are not screenshots... but the one you include now doesn't show the important parts of the form.  (and sometimes these parts are added to the DOM after certain actions are taken...)

Comment: @pcalkins I included the XPaths from all the lines in the form regarding that specific button, I don't know if that is what you asked for. I really don't know what I'm doing and it shows. Please, if you need any more information to solve this with Selenium, keep asking until I provide something useful. I'm very thankful.

Comment: There will be a <form> tag... inside of that (in between <form> and </form>) there will be various <input> fields.  Look for the one that has <input type="file">.  That's the part of the markup you should post.

Comment: @pcalkins Sorry for wasting your time. Is this what I need to show?

Comment: wasting time is what this site is for!  (jk...)  That's it!  So that's the element you want to send keys to.  Send it the path to your file.... (depending on how this site works you may also need to trigger the submit... depends on if a submit button is there or not.)  It's likely someone with an instagram account and knowledge of python will chime in with an answer soon...

Comment: ...see "submit()" method: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_Submit.htm  (so element.submit();)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind, I recommend a package that might help and works so good!

Instabot is capable to upload photos/videos & stories emulating a mobile device.

Installation:

```
pip install instabot
```

Implementation:

```
#Call bot
from instabot import Bot
```

Then only need a few more steps:

```
bot = Bot() 
bot.login(username = 'user',  password = 'pass')
bot.upload_photo(image_path, caption = 'Hello world')
```

I recommend this option due to is clean, fast and reliable

More info, visit: https://pypi.org/project/instabot/